# show/hide grid-view column by column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datagridviewcolumn

I'm creating a web project in Visual Studio 2012 using C# which fetch data from database and shows in a grid-view. There are many number of columns in the database, which shows on the grid-view as it is. I want to make an option for the user to eliminate unwanted columns using check-boxes and after checking, on a button click it must update.

I found how to hide a column by its column name. I need to find out how can I display it with the column name.

```
if (CheckBox3.Checked)
{
    dt.Columns.Remove("Site_name");
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    dt.Columns.Show("Site_name"); //I want a code to display, using column name.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a very simple way show and hide a particular column using check-box on a button click.

```
 if (CheckBox3.Checked == false)
 {
    dt.Columns.Remove("Site_name");
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: How does this answer your question how to show it again?

Comment: Here, when the checkbox is unchecked the condition satisfies and it will show the column and when the check-box is checked this condition will not execute so the column will will not show up.

Comment: but i thought that the question was how you can show the column again after it was removed.

Comment: Yes, you understood it right. Technically when the page loads all the columns will be displayed on the grid-view. Since, all the check boxes will be checked by default. After the page load user can modify the table by just unchecking the check-boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I would not remove the whole column from the `DataTable`, then you can't get it back if the user wants to show it (without relaoding all from database or whatever). I would show/hide that column only.

You have to find the index of the column first. [`DataControlFieldCollection.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcollection.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) only supports to find an index by a `DataControlField` not by it's `HeaderText`. If you often need to find the index of a `GridView`-column by it's name you can use this extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int GetColumnIndex(this DataControlFieldCollection columns, string columnName, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index <  columns.Count; index++)
            if(columns[index].HeaderText.Equals(columnName, comparison))
                return index;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this code:

```
int colIndex = GridView1.Columns.IndexOf("Site_name");
GridView1.Columns[colIndex].Visible = isColumnVisible; // acc. to your logic
```

Comment: Is there any other way to display the column as soon as the check-box is unchecked??

Comment: @Jilu: what way are you looking for? Of course you could modify the sql that fills the `DataTable`. You could use `SELECT Col1, Site_name ...` or `SELECT Col1 ...` according to the checked state. I thought that providing a way that does not even need to load the table again from database would be preferred.

Comment: Actually I'm using a data set to hold the data's from the database.