# How to hide gridview column by column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

my question is : how to hide gridview particular column using caolumn name?
i want hide column by  radiobutton chekced_chenged event but this is by index but i want to hide using column name.sorry for my bad english.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CGST Per Unit">
    <ItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="txtCGSTAmount" runat="server" Width="100px" TextMode="Number" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SGST Per Unit">
  <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="txtSGSTAmount" runat="server" Width="100px" TextMode="Number" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IGST Per Unit" Visible="false">
  <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="txtIGSTAmount" runat="server" TextMode="Number" Width="100px" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

         protected void rdbtnCGSTSGST_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (grvViewData.Columns.Count > 0)
                    {
                        grvViewData.Columns[5].Visible= true;
                        grvViewData.Columns[6].Visible= true;
                        grvViewData.Columns[7].Visible= false;
                    }
                }
                protected void rdbtnIGST_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (grvViewData.Columns.Count > 0)
                    {
                        grvViewData.Columns[7].Visible = true;
                        grvViewData.Columns[5].Visible = false;
                        grvViewData.Columns[6].Visible = false;

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show/hide grid-view column by column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639693/show-hide-grid-view-column-by-column-name)

Answer (score 0):

First of all , it is very unclear what you asking but still as per my understanding here is what i can understand 
You dont need to put c# code for this , keep the server free from these overheads whenever possible , now a days you have things like bootstarp 

use media query to hide a column or multiple column [Check this out](https://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/)

```
@media only screen  {
#unseen table td:nth-child(4),
#unseen table th:nth-child(4),
#unseen table td:nth-child(7),
#unseen table th:nth-child(7),
#unseen table td:nth-child(8),
#unseen table th:nth-child(8){display: none;}
}
```

or use javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:radio[name=rdbtnCGSTSGST]:checked').change(function () {
             $('table tr').each(function() { 
                $('td:eq(' index here  ')',this).hide();
             });

        });
    });
</script>
```